# How can I disable building archive for arm64 CPU on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, armv7, arm64

I have too many warnings on building for archive. And no errors on building for x32 devices or simulator.

How can I disable building archive for arm64 CPU on Xcode?

I've tried to set `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` on project's Build Settings to `armv7 armv7s` or `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` and `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES` but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES` in Build Settings
Also set `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` or `armv7 and armv7s` in **Architectures** and remove the `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`.

Do it in every single place and on all dependent projects in your workspace

Comment: The same build settings for static library helps me!